# How to search fields using Join?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, join

i have following columns:

```
Employee Name:

Department:

Designation:

                  Search Button
```

I wanted to write the Search query by joining tables.
How will be the search query?

I just want a search query using inner join.

I tried the following:

```
select e.empname, d.depname,designation 
from employee e  
inner join Department d on e.deptid=d.deptid 
inner join Designation de on de.deid=
where empname LIKe '"+Textbox1.text+'%'"' 
   or depname Like '"+ddldept.SelectedValue+"' 
   or designation Like '"+ddldesignation.SelectedValue+"'
```

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields...

Comment: @jarlh - To be fair, it does depend on the database you're using. For instance, Ms Access refers to columns as fields...

Comment: what database you are using?

Comment: I have used this query in C# code..

Comment: @JunRikson..Sql server but i wrote this query in c# code by using SqlCommand..

Comment: check my answer, I assume the table like that. Update your question if you have different table / model

Comment: @Paul, Access is more like Excel... Does it really count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using SQL Server.
And your tables to be like this :

```
Employee { id, deptid, empname }
Department { id, depname }
Designation { id, empid, designation }

select e.empname, d.depname, de.designation 
from Employee e  
inner join Department d on e.deptid = d.id 
inner join Designation de on e.id = de.empid
where e.empname LIKe '%"+Textbox1.text+"%' 
   or d.depname Like '%"+ddldept.SelectedValue+"%' 
   or de.designation Like '%"+ddldesignation.SelectedValue+"%'
```

This is bad practice actually, it is better using parametered queries in c# :

```
string sql = "select e.empname, d.depname, de.designation " +
    "from Employee e " +
    "inner join Department d on e.deptid = d.id " +
    "inner join Designation de on e.id = de.empid " +
    "where e.empname LIKe '%@empname%' " +
    "   or d.depname Like '%@deptname%' " +
    "   or de.designation Like '%@designation%'"; 

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(/* connection info */))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empname", Textbox1.text);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@deptname", ddldept.SelectedValue);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", ddldesignation.SelectedValue);
    var results = command.ExecuteReader();
}
```

Comment: hi sir ..Is it mandatory to write the query using + like...  + " from emplyee e " +....can i write the plain query without + and quotes?

Comment: + is c# syntax for concat or add string. I assume you are binding the form direclty into query which is really bad practice for avoiding sql injection. I suggest you are using parametered queries like in my updated answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Employee.id, Employee.NAME, Department.NAME, Designation.Name FROM Employee
INNER JOIN Department
ON Employee.id = Department.employee_id;
INNER JOIN Designation
ON Employee.id = Designation.employee_id;
WHERE Employee.NAME LIKE '%EmployeeInput%';
WHERE Department.NAME LIKE '%DepartmentInput%';
WHERE  Designation.Name LIKE '%DesignationInput%';
```

Maybe this will be helpful.